# BarLegend with a log scaling

Tags: plotting, legending

I have bar with log scale:

```
 BarLegend[{(Blend[{{Log10@1, White}, {Log10@10, Cyan}, {Log10@100, 
   Blue}}, Log10@#] &), {1, 100}}, Ticks -> {1, 10, 100}]
```

with result

[image].

How to get log-scale on the bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty here is that there are two different spaces you are working in and you have to know where each is being used. Specifically, we want the ticks in $\log_{10}$ space, but the *labels* in linear space. So, we have to specify the labels, too, to make it work correctly, e.g.

```
logTicks[min_, max_] := {#, 10^#} & /@ FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5]
```

Unfortunately, `Ticks` does not accept a function in `BarLegend`, otherwise I would do this

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 5}}, Ticks -> logTicks]
```

Instead, the range needs to be specified

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 5}}, Ticks -> logTicks[0,5]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Mathematica 12. Doing what you do, ticks appear reads in my code (but the code is working). Why so ?

Comment: @StarBucK if you run `Options@BarLegend`, you'll notice `Ticks` is not in the list. The FE at some point (can't remember exactly when) started marking unknown options red, even if they fell into a hidden list. So, treat the red as just a warning.

Answer (score 3):

```
BarLegend[
 {
  {White, Cyan, Blue},
  {0, Power[10, 6]}
  }
 , Power[10, Range[0, 5]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank but how to get smooth blend, with 1=White, 10=Cyan and 100= Blue?

Comment: See the answer by rcollyer.