# BarLegend with Non-linear Scale

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, legending

And wouldn't you know it...  I found this in the "Linked" section.

[BarLegend with a log scaling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174184/barlegend-with-a-log-scaling?rq=1)

HOWEVER, it still doesn't work with a ColorDataFunction, i.e...

```
BarLegend[{ColorData["SiennaTones"] , {0, 5}}, Ticks -> logTicks[0, 5]]
```

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I've done quite a lot of searching and experimenting with this.

I have a graphic that uses a non-linear scale and I'd like to make a bar legend for it.  As you can see below, I'm currently using a swatch legend (and people are giving me crap about it).

[image: 3d map graph]

```
mycf := Function[x, ColorData["SiennaTones"][-Log[1/x]/Log[10000]]]

BarLegend[{mycf, {1, 10000}}, 50]
```

gives

[image: bar legend from code above]

I've tried to use custom tick locations and that works for:

```
BarLegend["SiennaTones", {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}]
```

but not for:

```
In[]:= BarLegend[mycf, {0, 0.5, 1}]

Out[]= BarLegend[Function[x, ColorData["SiennaTones"][-(Log[1/x]/Log[10000])]], {0,0.5, 1}]
```

Comment: Include the function definition `logTicks[min_, max_] := {#, 10^#}& /@ FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5]` then `BarLegend[{"SiennaTones", {0, 5}}, Ticks -> logTicks[0, 5]]`